# Plugin based development core internal architecture in java

Tags: java, plugins, plugin-architecture

I have found below  styles for developing plugin

**1:java.util.ServiceLoader**

Working Style:Lookup in META-INF/services and get injected service

**Provide Abstract class to other implementor**

**2:java.net.URLClassLoader**

Working Style:Load a required class from a jar file and getinstance .

**Provide a interface to other implementor**

**3: Load from property file**

```
InputStream in =this.getClass().getClassLoader()
                .getResourceAsStream("packageName/config.properties");
```

Working Style 3:
Load class name from property file which implements the provided interface

**Provide a interface to other implementor**

Sample code  for 3

```
public interface PluginInterface {
    void performYourOperation();
};


public class PluginImpl implements PluginInterface {

    void performYourOperation() {
        //perform all operation what plugin is inteneded to do 

    }
    Main Loader:

     InputStream in =this.getClass().getClassLoader()
                .getResourceAsStream("packageName/config.properties");
    configProp.load(in );
            String factoryClass = (String) configProp
                    .get("plugin.factory.class");
            Class<?> factory = Class.forName(factoryClass);
            PluginInterface factory=(PluginInterface) factory.newInstance();
            factoryq.performYourOperation();

};
```

I have found 3 ways for own plugin implementation style  .

**Is there any other ways besides above  mentioned one .**

**Is maven and jenkins and other  its core level has the same style Or
 They have some more advance way ?**
Do any one have good idea for it.

Please  dont suggest to  use  this framework and that ,
i want to  learn and understand the core internal working  style.Thank You